# Compare the returned Json response with the posted response

Tags: javascript, groovy, jmeter, beanshell, post-processor

I have an API to save employee details to DB and I post the data using an HTTP POST API "/**empDetails**" and I post the details like "emp_name", "emp_id" and "emp_age"

Sample Payload,

```
{
 "emp_name": "Sam",
 "emp_age": "25",
 "emp_id": "M33214"
}
```

Once the data is successfully stored, I would invoke the GET "/**empDetails**" API to read the posted employee details.

Now I want to verify the returned data.
Sometimes the returned order might be jumbled. How can I verify the data using any custom assertions with the help of any language like JavaScript or Groovy or BeanShell?

P.S: I can add text response contains and can compare key-value pair.
But when the key-value pair count is more it would be difficult to add the assertion all the time. ex: the current payload have only 3 key-value pair, the sample payload may have additional fields too like "empReportingManager", "empAccount" etc..

Here the Post payload is read from a file using __FileToString() method.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Hari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as a child of the `GET` request
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def actual = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampleResult.getResponseDataAsString())

   def expected = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(new File('/path/to/request.json').text)

   if (actual != expected) {
       assertionResult.setFailureMessage(true)
       assertionResult.setFailureMessage('Mismatch between received and sent JSON')
   }
   ```

If JSON payload will match response (order does not really matter) the sampler will pass, otherwise you will get `Mismatch between received and sent JSON` message and the sampler will be marked as failed.

Check out [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) article for more details.

---

Note: for more complex JSON structures, i.e. if there are nested [JSON Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) it's better to go for [JSONAssert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) library.